# Navigation bar not displaying well in IE6,7,8 but works on 9 and all other browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

[www.tdeltd.net][1]

[1]: http://tdeltd.net is my site. The navigation bar is broken in all versions of IE except 9. All other browsers display the site properly. After two days of searching I am posting here as I cant find the solution. I get two errors on w3c validation but they are not relevant to the header and nav tags that the breakage is taking place within. I see some javascript related to IE versions in the head that point to files that do not exist. I am not sure where to get these. This design came from a template. CSS validated without errors so I am not sure where to put focus to try to fix ie6, 7 and 8 problems.

CSS for the header:

```
/* Header */
    header {
        height:262px;
        position:relative;
    }

/*===== header =====*/
header nav {
    height:50px;
    background:url(../images/nav-tail.gif) repeat-x left top;
    position:absolute;
    right:49px;
    top:201px;
    width:988px;
}
    header nav ul li {
        float:left;
    }
        header nav ul li a {
            font-size:1.273em;
            line-height:1.2em;
            font-weight:bold;
            color:#fff;
            text-decoration:none;
            display:block;
            padding:17px 20px 14px 20px;
        }
        header nav ul li a:hover,
        header nav ul li.current a {
            background-color:#df5b03;
            border-bottom:13px solid #0065a4;
        }
```

HTML is easily seen on the web by "get source" in ones browser. My challenge is that I only have a mac at my disposal and have to rely on others for feedback on breakage. Can anyone help guide me to a problem area or any potential ideas as to why this looks perfect on anything except previous version of IE? Many thank you's in advance!

Daryl

Thanks again for everyones help. Adding the html5shiv to the head section was a definite fix. Stack Overflow is great! Very glad I signed up and posted. My problem was solved within one hour. Took me longer to test and confirm than it did to get rock solid answers. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is something like the [`html5shim`](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/), that will enable HTML5 tags in IE (older than version 8). Requires JS, though...

Comment: Just put the html5shim in the head post the CSS links. I only have a mac so I cant test. The test page is http://tdeltd.net/index-10.html. Thanks for your reply. If you have the time can you take a peek to see if its looking okay?

Comment: @quotaholic it looks the same in IE7,8,9 here (:

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of IE do not support custom tags, such as the `<nav>` you have used. Use `<div class="nav">` instead for browser compatibility.

Comment: I am a little green on css and html changes. Will I need to change anything in the css to properly relate it to the changes made in the html document for this change?  Thank you for your fast reply!

Comment: Well, find references to `nav` and put a `.` in front (so `.nav`). That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ie versions less than 9 do not natively support html 5 elements like "nav." However, the fix is easy. By some weird quirk, if you create the element via JS (you don't even have to insert it into the DOM), IE will now know it exists and be able to style it.

So in your `<head>`, do this for each html5 element type you are using:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script>
document.createElement('nav');
//ditto for other html5 elements
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. I looked in another template I am working with for another customer and found an html5.js and within this I found this line:    `code`document.createElement("nav");`code`    Do you think I can just pop this html5.js in the js folder and leave the if then scripting in the head as is or should I adhere to your advice?

Comment: Cool - if you found it helpful, mind upvoting? It's not just for me (though it is nice to get points), but also helps other people who come across this answer visually see that it was helpful, should they have a similar question.

Comment: I would be happy to, how do I up vote? Rather new here... Thanks for the reply however my question on the html5.js being uploaded to the site is pending. Do you think that will be a viable fix?

Comment: No worries - see the number with the arrows above and below it at the top left of each answer? If you find an answer useful, click the up arrow (even for questions you didn't ask). If you ask a question and get the correct answer, click the check mark.

Comment: As for it being a fix - will help the rendering html5 elements in IE, but without doing a real walk-through of your code, I can't guess what other issues would come up.

Comment: Thank you! I just tried html5shim as I appreciate modular solutions. That and I trust the coding of experts over my own meddling. http://tdeltd.net/index-10.html is the copied test page. Is it possible to ask you to take a look to see if it is displaying as it should? Again I only have a mac to work on. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 elements are not available below IE 9.

The following code will fix that:

http://html5doctor.com/how-to-get-html5-working-in-ie-and-firefox-2/

```
<!--[if lt ie 9]>
    <script>
        document.createElement('nav')
    <script>
    <style>
        nav{display:block}
    </style>
<[endif]-->
```

Remember, it's important to style the tags after you create them in IE.

Your best bet is to use htmlshim, which is hosted on google code and likely cahched on the person's browser already:

```
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
```

Best performance is to put that in the head *after* the CSS.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I pasted the html5shim to a copied test page at http://tdeltd.net/index-10.html . As I only have a mac may I ask that someone look at this file to see if it is displaying correctly on Pre IE 9?   Thanks again!

Comment: blocked on my work's firewall... can you put the relevant code on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: This is using a standard jquery-1.4.2.min.js library. The looped slider is actually partially disabled. Left and right arrows are commented out until my customer gets more inventory. I dont know if this is relevant to the issues with ie as the breakage is taking place in a different area. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry. Your initial link is being blocked as "potentially harmful" and your jsfiddle link is also being blocked. I'm sure if you implimented html shiv properly, you're good to go. I recomend installing a vmware player virtual machine with windows on it for testing.

Comment: Good tip. Thank you for all of your help! Wish I could up vote. Stack Overflow is a tremendous resource. All of the tips were pointing in the same direction and hugely helpful in tackling my problem. Thanks to all who have helped. Once I get confirmation on the fix I will close the question.